# How to Pass Data from SvelteKit Hook to page

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, sveltekit

I'm working with SvelteKit to handle user authentication through JWT decoding in a server hook. I've successfully stored user data in 'sessionUser,' which is visible when I log event.locals. However, I'm encountering difficulties accessing this data in the load function within my +page.svelte file. Every time I log this data on the page it comes back as undefined. Any point in the right direction would be appreciated!

console log for event.locals.user
`{ user: { id: '1', email: 'useremail@yahoo.com' } }`

Hook Logic

```
     const sessionUser: SessionUser = {
        id: decoded.sub, 
        email: decoded.email, 
      };

      (event.locals as any).user = sessionUser; 
      console.log("event.locals", event.locals);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("JWT verification error:", error);
      (event.locals as any).user = null; 
    }
  } else {
    (event.locals as any).user = null;
  }

  return await resolve(event);
};
```

Test  for +page.svelt

```
   export const load: Load = ({ session }) => {
    const user = session.user;

    if (user) {
      let login = true;
    } else {
      let login = false;
    }

  };
```

Answer (score 3):

`locals` (not `session`) is [only available on the server](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#universal-vs-server-input), i.e. in the `load` of `+page.server.js`.